# Trigger before insert in MariaDB

Tags: triggers, insert, mariadb

I'm having some problem to create a new trigger before insert a new row. 
It should act before insert to stop an insert of a new row that has a value that is already referenced from another row in the same table.
I tried to use this trigger but it is not compatible with mariaDB, in fact it gives me asyntax error on referencing.

```
CREATE TRIGGER BadgeAlreadyUsed
BEFORE INSERT ON User
REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (EXISTS ( SELECT IDBadge FROM User WHERE N.IDBadge = User.IDBadge ))
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70002' ('Badge already used!!');
```

How i can do the same thing with the new syntax?
thanks.

Comment: Could you include the syntax error please. I suspect its the SQL after the `FOR EACH ROW` causing the problem.

Comment: I always used this syntax in db2 and i suppose that it is not compatible with mariaDB.

Comment: This is the error:
#1064 Syntax Error in SQL near 'REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (EXISTS ( SELECT IDBadge FROM User W' line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each database (DB2, MariaDB, etc) has hundreds of differences.  Don't assume anything!

This might be closer:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BadgeAlreadyUsed
    BEFORE INSERT ON User
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS ( SELECT IDBadge FROM User
           WHERE NEW.IDBadge = User.IDBadge ))
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70002'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Badge already used!!'; 
    END IF;
END;
```

Notice there there are at least 3 syntax changes (`WHEN`, `NEW`, `SET`).